# Set margin and custom border of a specific row for a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, border

How can I set the margin of a specific row in a `JTable` by its row number?

Please refer to the illustration below I made using excel.

[image]

Also, I want a thick border and an invisible border

Comment: What is the criteria (or condition) to render a row's  border in a specific way? For example, a row's data with certain column value, perhaps?

Comment: @prasad_ Yes. I already have a condition. It depends on a column value.

Answer (score 1):

`JTable` has a method `setRowHeight(...)` which will allow you to increase the height of specific rows.

Regarding the border you can check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/). It demonstrates how to override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the `JTable` to use a custom `Border`.

Comment: Can't I use setRowMargin method? I have an existing override for prepareRenderer. And I cannot modify it.

Comment: `Can't I use setRowMargin method?` - you tell me You know your reqirement better than I do. Did you try it? I would suggest it won't work because it will apply the margin for all rows and as I understand the question you only want this for specific rows. `I have an existing override for prepareRenderer. And I cannot modify it.` - why not? If you don't want to do that then you will need to provide custom renderers for each column in the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a `JTable` with custom row borders - for specific rows. These specific rows are determined by the data in the table rows.

The example uses a `JTable` with a custom renderer - `CustomBorderRenderer` class which extends `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer`. There are two classes in this example application: `TableCellRendererTester.java` and `CustomBorderRenderer.java`.

The following is the image of the table with custom border for a specific row - where the Year value is "2012". The source code for the two classes follow.

[image]

**The Example Code**:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableCellRendererTester {

    private static final Object[] TABLE_COLUMNS = {"Book", "Author", "Year"};
    private static final Object [][] TABLE_DATA = {
        {"Book 1", "author 1", "1972"}, {"Book 2", "author 1", "1945"},
        {"Book 3", "author 2", "2012"}, {"Book 4", "author 3", "1999"}
    };

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new TableCellRendererTester().createAndShowGUI();
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Custom Row Border Tester");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(getTablePanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getTablePanel() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(TABLE_DATA, TABLE_COLUMNS);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        CustomBorderRenderer renderer = new CustomBorderRenderer();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        scrollpane.setViewportView(table);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(scrollpane);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

**The Renderer Class**:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class CustomBorderRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private int prevRow;
    private boolean customBorderFlag;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        JComponent c = (JComponent) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (row != prevRow) {
            // Row has changed.
            // Store it so that all the columns can be rendered 
            // with the custom border - if condition is met.
            customBorderFlag = false;
            prevRow = row;
            TableModel m = table.getModel();
            String s = (String) m.getValueAt(row, 2);
            // Check if the row needs to be rendered with a custom border.
            if (s.equals("2012")) {
                customBorderFlag = true;
            }
        }

        if (customBorderFlag) {
            // Set custom border for all column cells - for a row.
            c.setBorder(getCustomBorder());
        }

        return c;
    }

    /*
     * Returns a custom border with:
     * 1. Thick border
     * 2. A margin between cell content (text) and the border.
     */
    private Border getCustomBorder() {
            Border insideMargin = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
            Border thickBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3);
            Border borderWithMargin = 
                BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(thickBorder, insideMargin);

            return borderWithMargin;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Updated the image and the `CustomBorderRenderer.java` class to show the custom border *with margin*.

Comment: Can't I use setRowMargin method? I already tried this, but it seems I cannot modify or rearrange the override for getTableCellRendererComponent. It already has an existing one.

Comment: Are you trying to set margin for particular row? Or all rows?

Comment: Yes, as specified on the question, specific row

Comment: It can be done using the custom renderer I have shown in my answer above - with small code change.

Comment: @gengencera I have updated the answer code with the margin (and thick border) for a specific row. See the updated code in the `CustomBorderRenderer.java` class.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for thick borders. But how about setting an invisible border? Like make the thick to invisible? I tried setting the border to null or to 0 as width but it didn't work.

Comment: Try using a White colored border - this might just make the border disappear into the background. -OR- Make the border thickness so thin (like 0 or 0.0001) that the border may not appear at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180395/discussion-between-prasad-and-gengencera).

Comment: Try using `BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()`. _-OR-_ Try WHITE colored border (this will make the border not show in the white background).